# Playa: Specify a default child entry if none is selected

Tags: templates, playa

I have a channel with a playa field where users can select a block of content to insert into a page.

Is there a way that I can specify a default child entry to display if the playa field is left blank?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One approach would be using a conditional based on [`no_children`](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html#variable-tags) variable:

```
{exp:playa:children field="your_field"}
    {if no_children}
        No children found...display fallback.
    {/if}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Or you might find that using a conditional based on the [`{exp:playa:total_children}`](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/total_children.html) tag is better suited:

```
{if "{exp:playa:total_children field='your_field'}"}
    No children found...display fallback.
    Perhaps open a channel entry loop here to show your fallback child
{/if}
```

Comment: I considered those options, but the problem is, I want to display a specific child entry, if none is specified, so my conditional would have to be another duplicate instance of my playa code, with a hard-coded entry_id. I'm trying to find a way to avoid doing that.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to avoid hard-coding an entry_id since you have to specify a child to show (either using Playa or a plain channel:entries tag). I take it it's the repeated html you don't care for? You could put the html  in a snippet.